# Why am I getting undefined on this module pattern in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Why am I getting undefined on the x.test()? It's an anonymous function.

```
var Calculator = function () {    
  // private stuff
  var x = 55;      
  return {
    // public members    
    y: x,
    test: function () {
      console.log(x);
    }
  };
}; 

var x = new Calculator(); 

console.log(x.y);
console.log(x.test());
```

Answer (score 2):

You're logging the *return value* of `x.test` which is implicitly `undefined`:

```
console.log(x.y); // Logs 55
var x = x.test(); // Logs 55 (because of the console.log call in x.test)
console.log(x); // Logs undefined (because that's what x.test returned)
```

Did you mean to return the "private" `x` from the `test` method?

```
// ...
return {
    y: x,
    test: function () {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are printing (`console.log`) the return of a function that doesn't return anything.

Just return the `x` value in your `test` function:

```
var Calculator = function () {
    // private stuff
    var x = 55;

    return {
        // public members
        y: x,
        test: function () {
            return x;
        }
    };
};
```